# How to increase label size of OpenLayers plugin basemap layers?

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

For QGIS 2.2.0-Valmiera, how does one increase the label size of OpenStreetMap layer or any other basemap layer?  Presently the labels are way too small to read.  For example, I find that for the same zoom level of a map in www.openstreetmap.com vs the same map in QGIS2.2, the map in QGIS2.2 has labels much smaller than the one from www.openstreetmap.com.  For illustration, click here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B27Gf4KIu-6-NFVhSV9zUFBDZGM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks guys, for the answers. Just wondering why the OpenLayers plugin developers decided to fetch higher-than-necessary resolution OSM/Google raster maps for a zoom level that clearly requires a lower resolution for optimal viewing of labels.

Comment: They decided for a seemless scale, taking the next greater tile and making it smaller. Taking the next smaller tile needs to expand it, which looks a bit weird.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't tune the map style itself, as the OL plugin makes use of the OSM tile maps  that consist of prerendered map tiles/images.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to the Openlayers plugin, you can call the OpenStreetmap tiles by a TMS service as described here:
*(Page not available per Feb 2021)*

http://www.3liz.com/blog/rldhont/index.php?post/2012/07/17/OpenStreetMap-Tiles-in-QGIS

The disadvantage is that the tiles only look good in the native resolution (as listed in the article), and other scales look a bit weird.

---

**EDIT**

You can use the TileMapScale Plugin to snap the scale to the optimal display of tiles: *(Plugin not available for QGIS > 3.0 )*

http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/TileMapScaleLevels/

You have to fetch the zip from https://github.com/datalyze-solutions/TileMapScaleLevels and expand it manually to your .qgis2/python/plugins folder.

Comment: that also doesn't work with map composer