# How to print out a road atlas with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, zoom, atlas

This is what I managed to do so far (first picture):

Through the web tab and quickmapservice or OpenLayers plugin I loaded maps where on I managed to add a vector grid under research tools to then go to a composer manager where I implemented the Atlas function.

I was successful in dividing the city map into 1km square parts, but when I print I end up with a map that has the correct zoom level and quality, but the roads and street/object names have shrunk and are too small to read (second picture).

[image: In the Atlas preview it looks good but when I print or export I get something else]

[image: this is what it looks like when I print or save as image/pdf]

Comment: They look the same size to me. I'd just increase the label sizes in the layers.

Comment: when i print an atlas page the street names are too small to read.. your "label size" remark led me to another post:

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92315/how-to-increase-label-size-of-openlayers-plugin-basemap-layers

seems to be the problem i am having. I installed the TileMapScale Plugin but i cannot seem to figure out how to use it.