# How can I get QGIS Print Composer to print OSM map at desired zoom level?

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

Like the title suggests, I'm trying to print a map that uses OSM Stamen data from the OpenLayers plugin.

My map looks like this in QGIS:
[image: Map view in QGIS]

And like this in the Print Composer:
[image: Map view in print composer]

But when I export the map to an image, it appears to be at a smaller zoom level.
[image: After exporting]

Is there any way to actually make the map look like I'm desiring? I came across [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92315/how-to-increase-label-size-of-openlayers-plugin-basemap-layers) thread, but it didn't lead me anywhere productive.

Comment: Aren't the maps in the print composer and the printed one on the same scale? The printed one seems to show the same extend, it is just more detailed. In my experience the print composer isn't displaying maps as detailed as they are.

Comment: Use quickmaps instead of openlayers plug in